# How to read a log file in Junit test

Tags: java, junit, log4j

I have a method that logs a string up on exception.
In my JUnit test I want to read the log and make sure the string exists in it.

Can someone suggest how to do this ?

Comment: Do you mean capture output to the console, or is the "log" you talk about a log file? If its to a file, just open the file and read it.

Answer (score 7):

If the method is logging to Log4J, you could create a mock appender and attach it to the class being tested.  After running the test, you can check the mock appender and insure that the correct string was logged to it.

Comment: It's customary to accept the answer that best answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

You want to test, that an expected message is send to the logger if an exception was caught. Parsing the log file is an option, but with that approach you'd test the logger configuration too (which should be out of scope for this test).

You could mock the logger and test, if the mock receives the expected message and the expected log level.

Or - use a special logger configuration for testing to receive the "raw" logging messages in a file or on the console (you could redirect that output to an internal print stream)